# How to print word on keypress after hit enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an example which it returns the input val string after hit enter, now I want to do the same thing but without the input with `keypress()` function and initialize that value everytime.

My exemple with input:

```js
jQuery("input#barcode").on("keydown",function search(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    var myval = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(myval);
    jQuery('#barcode').val(''); // Initialize the input value after getting the value.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="barcode" type="text" class="barcode" autofocus="autofocus" onfocus="this.select()"/>
```

Comment: Your code work, so what is problem?

Comment: @Mohammad: `now I want to do the same thing but without the input `

Comment: @PRINCE how do you want to do it without the input? Please explain EXACTLY what do you want to do.

Comment: It is not my question, it's PRINCE's question...I just highlighted what OP want

Comment: @SnakeEyes yeah sorry haha :P

Comment: **I want ... without the input with keypress()** So you want to get text of which element on `keypress()` of which element?

Comment: Guys something like this http://jsfiddle.net/hvfw5k9t/, but this exemple don't initialize the value

Comment: "without the input" - `$(document).on("keypress", ...`

Comment: The fiddle work but you need to focus on widow to working. http://jsfiddle.net/hvfw5k9t/1/

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "initialise the value"

Comment: Don't you mean like removing the `if` statement and fire the function on keypress everytime? Or like knockoutJS with binding it to your js viewmodel. Or use Angular/vue/react?

Comment: I mean by initialiaze the value exemple if I hit `aze` then enter, it return `aze`good, now if i hit again `rty` then enter it should return `rty` and not `azerty` like my jsffidle in the above comment

Comment: `if (enter) { alert(..); myval=''; }` ?  not sure what the problem is  - updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvfw5k9t/2/

Comment: So by "initialise" you mean "clear" or "reset".  Kind-of the opposite meaning :)

Comment: yes clear, sorry

Comment: @freedomn-m it doesn't do the trick without the else http://jsfiddle.net/hvfw5k9t/5/

Comment: So why did you remove the `else`?

Comment: because I dont understand why i should put it in else, logically when I hit enter, it should return the value from the if

Comment: Just read what it does - when you press a key, if it's not enter, add it to the variable - if it is enter, show what's been typed then clear the value.  Of course you need the `else` otherwise your previous keypresses aren't recorded (which *appears* to be what you are trying to achieve).

Answer (score 0):

hope this is what you need..

```js
var newVal = '';
var oldVal = '';
jQuery("input#barcode").on("keydown",function search(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    var myval = jQuery(this).val();
    newVal = myval.replace(oldVal,'');
    oldVal = oldVal+newVal
    alert(newVal);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="barcode" type="text" class="barcode" autofocus="autofocus" onfocus="this.select()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but without the input as I explained in the question :)

Comment: input  in  this statment you ,mean " jQuery("input#barcode").on("keydown",function search(e) { " ?

or input element tag ?

Comment: input element tag